# jQuery Accordion Closed at Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I get the accordion widget to be closed when the page loads? This is the code I'm using:

```
//Accordion
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
```

Also, it may be unimportant but the accordion divs are inside dialog divs.

Comment: "accordion divs are inside dialog divs" - what do you mean? Can you paste your HTML? The jQuery accordion implementation has semantic requirements. The markup requires pairs of headers and divs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `active` option being set to `false` *should* (according to the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active)) cause the menu to be collapsed on page-load (though it specifically requires `collapsible: true` (which you already have).

If this isn't already in a `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()` then it needs to be wrapped in one of those; if it *is* so wrapped then without a demo (perhaps [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?) it's difficult to suggest what might be happening, or going wrong.

Is the remainder of the JavaScript (beyond the call to `.accordion()` being executed? If not there might be a JS error, somewhere. It might be worth running it through [JS Lint](http://jslint.com) to be sure.

Comment: The code is not in a $(document).ready() but the script is at the end of the body, so it should not matter right? All of the javascript is running flawlessly except for this.

Comment: I'd recommend *trying* it in a `$(document).ready()`, if only to rule out one *possible* solution. I'd *definitely* recommend posting a demo (on either of the sites in my answer) so that we can see it working/not-working and suggest answers. Without the html it's difficult to help.

Comment: In preparing a jsbin to show you, I discovered there is an odd conflict between a colorpicker plugin I was using and the dialog widget. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yottagray: no problem at all, though I wish I'd been a little more *specifically* useful... :)

Comment: Thanks thanks made a difference however, it flashes the expanded content very quickly onload

Answer (score 0):

The index value can be boolean or integer

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=AccordionIndexHidden.ClientID %>').val());
        if (activeIndex < 0) 
            activeIndex = false;
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            event: "mousedown",
            active: activeIndex,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                $('#<%=AccordionIndexHidden.ClientID %>').val(index);
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Remember to start with index less than 0

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="AccordionIndexHidden" runat="server" Value="-1" />
```

FYI, the hidden field is to keep save the accordions open between postbacks